# How to handle multiple async tasks in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs, asynchronous, callback

Working on a sandbox app to learn angular.js I have encountered the following pattern in several places in my code. I find myself having to query the mongoDB in a loop. As I understand it, each call happens in its own async task. How do I know when all the tasks are completed?

For instance, I have an array of *states*. Often I need to set *someProperty* to *someNewValue* for each of the states. Once all the states have been updated I would like to call *someFunction()*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.states.length; i++) {
    $scope.states[i].someProperty = someNewValue;
    $scope.states[i].$update({stateId: $scope.states[i].id}, function() {
        someFunction();
    });
}
```

For now, the only way I can think of doing this is to call *someFunction()* every time each *update* succeeds. I know there must be a smarter and better way of doing this.

What would you be your approach?

Comment: I answered a similar question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144132/chaining-promise-and-defered-with-a-for-loop-in-angular-application/20144522#20144522

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Promises and `$q.all` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)) are your friends.

In more detail, you will have to make a promise for each call (if the call itself does not return one), push them in an array and call `$q.all(promises).then(allFinished)`. Naive case, where `$update()` does not return a promise:

```
function callUpdate(x, promises) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    x.$update({stateId: $scope.states[i].id}, function() {
        someFunction();
        d.resolve(); // it may be appropriate to call resolve() before someFunction() depending on your case
    });
    promises.push(d.promise);
}

...

var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.states.length; i++) {
    $scope.states[i].someProperty = someNewValue;
    callUpdate($scope.states[i], promises);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    // called when all promises have been resolved successully
});
```

The reason for the existence of `callUpdate()` is to encapsulate the deferred object handling and return the promise.